# Attempted to leave type `PointerState` uninitialized

Tags: rust, rust-piston

I wanted to try to make a game in Rust using Piston. This is the first time I have used this library. I took this code from the official doc to test it. However, when my mouse touches the application window it closes immediately and I don’t understand why.

```
extern crate glutin_window;
extern crate graphics;
extern crate opengl_graphics;
extern crate piston;

use glutin_window::GlutinWindow as Window;
use opengl_graphics::{GlGraphics, OpenGL};
use piston::event_loop::{EventSettings, Events};
use piston::input::{RenderArgs, RenderEvent, UpdateArgs, UpdateEvent};
use piston::window::WindowSettings;

pub struct App {
    gl: GlGraphics, // OpenGL drawing backend.
    rotation: f64,  // Rotation for the square.
}

impl App {
    fn render(&mut self, args: &RenderArgs) {
        use graphics::*;

        const GREEN: [f32; 4] = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0];
        const RED: [f32; 4] = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0];

        let square = rectangle::square(0.0, 0.0, 50.0);
        let rotation = self.rotation;
        let (x, y) = (args.window_size[0] / 2.0, args.window_size[1] / 2.0);

        self.gl.draw(args.viewport(), |c, gl| {
            // Clear the screen.
            clear(GREEN, gl);

            let transform = c
                .transform
                .trans(x, y)
                .rot_rad(rotation)
                .trans(-25.0, -25.0);

            // Draw a box rotating around the middle of the screen.
            rectangle(RED, square, transform, gl);
        });
    }

    fn update(&mut self, args: &UpdateArgs) {
        // Rotate 2 radians per second.
        self.rotation += 2.0 * args.dt;
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Change this to OpenGL::V2_1 if not working.
    let opengl = OpenGL::V3_2;

    // Create an Glutin window.
    let mut window: Window = WindowSettings::new("spinning-square", [200, 200])
        .graphics_api(opengl)
        .exit_on_esc(true)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    // Create a new game and run it.
    let mut app = App {
        gl: GlGraphics::new(opengl),
        rotation: 0.0,
    };

    let mut events = Events::new(EventSettings::new());
    while let Some(e) = events.next(&mut window) {
        if let Some(args) = e.render_args() {
            app.render(&args);
        }

        if let Some(args) = e.update_args() {
            app.update(&args);
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempted to leave type `platform::platform::x11::util::input::PointerState` uninitialized, which is invalid', /home/zenmoa/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/mem/mod.rs:658:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is apparently a [bug in an old version of `winit`](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/issues/1773), which is fixed in the latest `winit` release. However, various crates e.g. amethyst, piston, ggez, etc. still use `winit` 0.19. In Rust 1.48.0 the issue has apparently manifested itself as a panic.

On the amethyst issue tracker a [comment](https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst/issues/2524#issuecomment-731516791) mentions, that for now a possible workaround is to revert back to Rust 1.47.0. If you're using `rustup`, then you can do that by executing the following command:

```sh
rustup default 1.47.0
```